# Ubuntu 18.04 backup

Tags: 18.04, client

I have a desktop that has 1 ssd and 1 hdd.  I want to write a script that will allow me to preform a backup of my ssd and store it on hdd.  Is this something that I can do?  I am unsure if the backup can be stored on the hdd of the same computer.  Thanks in advance for assistance on this matter.

Ice701

Comment: What are you trying to back up? In my view system and data back-ups should be treated separately, and I use different methods for each.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to write a script for this backup rather than using an existing application?

Comment: @PaulBenson, I do understand that they should be separated as mine are.  However, my intent is to have the individual client take its own snapshot and place it on that hdd.  From there I will move the snapshots to my local file server.

Comment: @Broadsworde, it is a better fit for the company that I work for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 18.xx's `Backups` application to backup select folders in your home directory.

Use `timeshift` to backup OS to snapshots.

Use `Macrium Reflect` to make clone copies of the entire disk.

---

The closest thing to a Windows-like restore point is by using `Timeshift`. I use it to save snapshots to an external USB hard drive. Although it can, it's normally not used for backing up your /home directory, just system-level changes. Use `Backups` (Déjà Dup) for backing up /home files.

```
Timeshift is a system restore utility which takes snapshots
of the system at regular intervals. These snapshots can be restored
at a later date to undo system changes. Creates incremental snapshots
using rsync or BTRFS snapshots using BTRFS tools.
```

More information at https://github.com/teejee2008/timeshift

Add the PPA and install with:

`sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:teejee2008/ppa`

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt install timeshift`

Comment: thanks for the knowledge.  I think this may work for my needs.  I will test this and reply back.  Thanks for your assistance on this matter.